# Get the $rootScope from a DOM element

Tags: angularjs

I'm traversing the DOM to count up all the scopes in an angular appliation.

I'm using this method:

```
angular.element(document.body).data().$scope
```

This works for any other dom element that has a scope on it, but doesn't find the $rootScope ever.

Is there a way to get to the `$rootScope` from the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `$rootScope` off any scope using the `$root` property:

`angular.element(document.body).scope().$root;`
`angular.element(anyOtherElementWithScope).scope().$root;`

Comment: I'll call it. Think it's not possible and yours is the best method :)

Comment: Right, not attached to the node directly. Angular extends jQlite (or your preferred jQuery) with a `scope()` method. It's probably worth pointing out here that you'd generally only use it if you were writing something really low-level, or some kind of debugger (which it sounds like you're doing).